# Setting up associations / db references rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

I have a table called bills. Bills has_many sponsors and has_many cosponsors. Both sponsors and cosponsors contains a list of congress people. I also have a table called congress_people. On the congress_people show page I would like to display a table that shows what bills the congress person sponsor and one that shows what bills they cosponsor. Any idea on how I could do this? I know to generate the tables but I am not sure how to set up the association. I am using rails 4.2 and mysql2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `has_many_through` association, roughly like this:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sponsorships, -> { where(kind: :primary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship"
  has_many :cosponsorships, -> { where(kind: :secondary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship"

  has_many :sponsors, class_name: 'CongressPerson', through: :sponsorships
  has_many :cosponsors, class_name: 'CongressPerson', through: :cosponsorships
end

class Sponsorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # schema bill_id(INT), sponsor_id(INT), kind(STRING)
  belongs_to :bill
  belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: "CongressPerson"
end

class CongressPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sponsorships, -> { where(kind: :primary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship", foreign_key: :sponsor_id
  has_many :cosponsorships, -> { where(kind: :secondary) }, class_name: "Sponsorship", foreign_key: :sponsor_id

  has_many :sponsored_bills, through: :sponsorships, source: :bill
  has_many :cosponsored_bills, through: :cosponsorships, source: :bill

end
```

Here's a basic migration for the `Sponsorship` table:

```
class CreateSponsorships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sponsorships do |t|
      t.references :bill
      t.references :sponsor
      t.string :kind

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to make calls like the following:

```
@bill.sponsors
# => returns the congress_people sponsoring the bill

@bill.cosponsors
# => returns the congress_people cosponsoring the bill

@congress_person.sponsored_bills
# => returns the bills sponsored by the congress person

@congress_person.cosponsored_bills
# => returns the bills cosponsored by the congress person
```

Then in your `CongressPerson` show view:

```
<%= @congress_person.sponsored_bills.each do |sponsored| %>
  # populate your HTML table row
<% end %>
<%= @congress_person.cosponsored_bills.each do |cosponsored| %>
  # populate your HTML table row
<% end %>
```

Comment: For the sponsorship table would I use add_reference for the bill_id & sponsor_id?

Comment: @Taylor I just added an example migration for the `Sponsorship` table. I also tweaked the active record relationships to make this clearer. Hope it helps!

Comment: So I tweaked somethings and was able to get my form to show up but instead of getting a dropdown with names in it, I get a text box with #<Sponsorship::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fcd54ac3018> in it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Taylor: Sounds like you've got something like `f.text_area :method`, where `:method` is an active record association. You probably want a select box instead, i.e. `f.select` -- though that's not going to work with an association either. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do. I'd recommend you make a separate question for this and someone can help you out!

Comment: @Taylor If this answer was helpful to you, would you consider accepting it or at least up voting it? Appreciate it!